# C#5 async return types -clarification?

Tags: .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

From [*here :*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

> Async methods can return `Task<T>`, `Task`, or `void`.
>   Why return `Task<T>` or `Task`? Because they're awaitable, and void is
>   not. So if you have an async method returning `Task<T>` or `Task`, then
>   you can pass the result to await.

Now consider this example :

```
/*1*/    public async Task<int> CalculateAnswer()
/*2*/       {
/*3*/         await Task.Delay(100); 
/*4*/        
/*5*/         // Return a type of "int", not "Task<int>"
/*6*/         return 42;
/*7*/       }
```

I **do understand** that the moment the control enters the `async` method and meets the `await` operator , it first check to see if the awaitable has finished , if it has then it runs regular(sync). **and if it didn't , it returns from the `async` method.**

Ok so it returns and we need to keep an eye on the async task. and I guess thats why we have `Task<T>` at the method signature.

**Question**

But Why do I need `int` in the  `Task<int>` ? **the awaitable has nothing(!) to do with INT !!** -- it could be a webservice downloading something. in order to keep an eye on the async operation i could use `Task` only.

So **Either** the `Task<t>` is there to keep an eye for the `async` operation **OR(!!!)** is it there to indicate the return value of the method ?

I'm confused. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two tasks in this example.

The task returned by `CalculateAnswer` is a `Task<int>`. It represents the method `CalculateAnswer`. That task will complete when `CalculateAnswer` completes, and its result (an `int`) will be the return value of that method.

The other task is the one returned by `Task.Delay`. That one is just a `Task`; there's no result value. That task represents the delay.

Comment: so `Task<int>` has nothing to do with the async operation itself ?

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the `await`, no.